# Для чего используется QTreeWidgetItem::setData

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Для чего нам нужен  QTreeWidgetItem::setData(int column, int role, const QVariant & value), если в результате отображение данных всё равно текстовом формате? Пример использования:

```
 void AbonentWidget::updateTreeItem( QTreeWidgetItem* pTreeWidgetItem, const AMR::CMeterParams& oMeterParams )
    {
        AMR_ASSERT( oMeterParams.isValidSerialNum() );

        if( pTreeWidgetItem )
        {
            AMR::DatabaseStruct::CCommissioning oCommissioning = AMR::Settings().getDatabase().load_commissioning( oMeterParams.getCommissioningUuid() );

            pTreeWidgetItem->setData( 0, Qt::UserRole, oMeterParams.getModelStr() );// зачем используется здесь?

            pTreeWidgetItem->setText( 0, oMeterParams.getFamilyString()   );// если в результате используем здесь?
            pTreeWidgetItem->setText( 1, oMeterParams.getModelStrCustom() );
            pTreeWidgetItem->setText( 2, oMeterParams.getSerialStr()      );
            pTreeWidgetItem->setText( 3, oMeterParams.getFirmware()       );
            pTreeWidgetItem->setText( 4, oCommissioning.getPeriod()       );
        }
        else AMR_ASSERT_FALSE();
    }
```

Comment: Ну `UserRole` же, пользовательские данные. `Qt::UserRole 32 The first role that can be used for application-specific purposes.` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)

Comment: @gil9red А что означают пользовательские данные? И для чего вообще нужен этот параметр?

Comment: Внутренние данные, что не должны отображаться или как то влиять на элементы контейнера

Comment: @gil9red По приведённому мною коду если закомментировать строку  pTreeWidgetItem->setData( 0, Qt::UserRole, oMeterParams.getModelStr() ); то ничего не происходит, а если строку pTreeWidgetItem->setText( 0, oMeterParams.getFamilyString()   ); то отображается пустая ячейка

Comment: Поищите в вашем коде `data(Qt::UserRole)` и найдете место откуда те данные вытаскиваются, чтобы понять для чего это вообще было нужно. Ну а как иначе? Если закомментировали `setText` то в ячейке будет пустая строка и, соответственно, сама ячейка будет пустой

Comment: Считайте, что setText это как setData с ролью Qt::DisplayRole.
pTreeWidgetItem->setData( 0, Qt::DisplayRole, oMeterParams.getModelStr() )

Comment: @gil9red  Т.е. Qt::UserRole служит индикатором того, что в QTreeWidgetItem::setData(int column, int role, const QVariant & value) вместо const QVariant & value будет объект моего класса использоваться?

Comment: не, `Qt::UserRole`, `Qt::UserRole + 1`, `Qt::UserRole + 2` и т.д. просто контейнеры ваших объектов типа QVariant, а уже QVariant может принимать кучу стандартных типов и классов, плюс пользовательские, но это уже тема другого вопроса

Comment: Qt::UserRole необходима, чтобы получать данные об итеме, через интерфейс модели. Представьте, что у вас есть только указатель на модель (model*), вам нужно получить поле итема (ModelItem::x), тогда в  функции модели data(const QModelIndex& index, int role), вы определяете, что будет возвращено при Qt::UserRole + 1, а именно return ModelItem::getX(). И теперь можете писать x = model->data(index, Qt::UserRole + 1).toX();

Comment: @awesome Т.е. строчка pTreeWidgetItem->setData( 0, Qt::UserRole, oMeterParams.getModelStr() ); в коде не случайна? И получается, что item хранит в себе 2 сущности: 1) data 2) Text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С ролью Qt::UserRole первый вызов

```
setData(int column, int role, const QVariant& value)
```

добавит в столбец column QTreeWidgetItem'а роль Qt::UserRole со значением value. Каждый последующий вызов setData с тем же столбцом(column) и ролью(Qt::UserRole) будет изменять значение(value), которое соответствует этой роли.

Роль это просто признак для модели, какой из методов для чтения или записи внутренних членов будет вызван у итема.
Внутри итема может быть много данных, которые инизиализируются при его создании, например картинка заднего фона. Мы можем как получить ссылку на картинку вызвав у модели data(...) c необходимой ролью Qt::DecorationRole

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, Qt::DecorationRole)
```

так и перезаписать эту картинку вызвав уже setData()

```
bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, Qt::DecorationRole)
```

Для примера метод data(...)

```
QVaraint MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, Qt::DecorationRole) const
{
  if(index.isValid() == false)
    return QVariant();

  QVariant result;

  MyItem* item = static_cast<MyItem*>(index.internalPointer());

  switch (role):
  {
    case Qt::DecorationRole:
     result = item->getBackground();
     break;
    case Qt::UserRole + 1:
      result = item->getUserRolePlusOneValue();
      break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Каждый QTreeWidgetItem внутри содержит вектор:

```
QVector< QVector<QWidgetItemData> > values;
```

где, `QVector<QWidgetItemData>` это вектор пар (роль, значение), то есть для каждого столбца у вас есть множество ролей, в соответствии с которыми вы получаете значения.
Еще раз, вызвав для итема

```
pQTreeWidgetItem->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, const QVariant& value);
```

вы добавляете нулевому столбцу итема роль Qt::UserRole со значением value; вы можете прочитать это значение вызвав

```
value val = pQTreeWidgetItem->data(0, Qt::UserRole).toValue();
```

Comment: Т.е. в моём примере pTreeWidgetItem->setData( 0, Qt::UserRole, oMeterParams.getModelStr() ); получается лишним т.к. данные сразу же переписывается вызовом  pTreeWidgetItem->setText(0, oMeterParams.getFamilyString() ); ?

Comment: Я изменил свой ответ, перечитайте с самого начала.